# unable to convert a json to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a huge JSON file to a data frame in order to preprocess it for sentiment analysis.But unable to convert it.

The problem is at pd.read_json

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("/content/drive/My Drive/timeline_1.jsonl") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"
    data_df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)
```

ValueError: Unmatched ''"' when decoding 'string'

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell without seeing the actual JSON. It looks like your JSON formatting is off. Perhaps you're missing a ' somewhere?

Comment: Please paste a sample of the JSON file

Answer (score 0):

Your data is probably corrupted, at least in one place (maybe more).

**One method** to find such a place is to run your code, not on the whole file,
but on chunks of it.

For example, run your code on:

- the first half of your file,
- the second half.

If any part runs OK, then it is free from errors.

The next step is to repeat the above procedure on each "failed" chunk.

**Another method**: Look thoroughly at your StackTrace, maybe somewhere there is
the line number in the **source file** (do not confuse it with the line number
of **Python code**).

For now you assemble the whole text as a **single** line, so even if the StackTrace
contains such number, it is most likely just *1*.

To ease your investigation, change your code in such a way that each
source line is in a **separate** line in the joined text. Something like:

```
data_json_str = "[" + ',\n'.join(data) + "]"
```

Then execute your code again and read the number shown (where the error occurred),
now equal to the number of source line.

Then look at this line, correct it and your code should run with no error.

## Edit after your comment with source data

In your data I noticed that:

- it contains **two** JSON objects (rows),
- but **without** any comma between them.

I made the following completions and changes:

- added *[* and *]* at the beginning / end,
- added a comma after the first *{...}*.

so that the input string was:

```
data_json_str = '''[
{"id": "99014576299056245", "created_at": "2017-11-16T14:28:53.919Z",
 "sensitive": false, "spoiler_text": "", "language": "en",
 "uri": "mastodon.gamedev.place/users/jaggy/statuses/99014576299056245",
 "instance": "mastodon.gamedev.place",
 "content": "<p>Coding a cheeky skill before bed. Not as much as I&apos;d like but had drinks with co-workers after work so shrug ^_^</p>",
 "account_id": "434", "tag_list": [], "media_attachments": [], "emojis": [], "mentions": []},
{"id": "99014544879467317", "created_at": "2017-11-16T14:20:54.462Z", "sensitive": false}
]'''
```

Then performed your instruction to read this string:

```
data_df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)
```

and got a DataFrame with 2 rows (no error).
Initially I suspected `&apos;` as a possible source of error, but *read_json*
did cope also with this case.

But when I deleted the comma after the first *{...}*, I got error:

```
ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)
```

(other error than yours).

I use *Python* 3.7.0 and *Pandas* 0.25.
If you have some older version of either *Python* or *Pandas*, maybe you should
upgrade them?

The real problem is probably connected with some "weak point" in JSON
parser (I'm not sure wherher it is a part of *Python* or *Pandas*).

Before you upgrade, perform another test: Drop the mentioned `&apos;` from
the input string and attempt *read_json* again.

If you get this time a proper result, this will confirm my suspicion
that the JSON parser in your installation has flaws and will be an
important support of my advice to upgrade your software.

Comment: {"id": "99014576299056245", "created_at": "2017-11-16T14:28:53.919Z", "sensitive": false, "spoiler_text": "", "language": "en", "uri": "https://mastodon.gamedev.place/users/jaggy/statuses/99014576299056245", "instance": "mastodon.gamedev.place", "content": "<p>Coding a cheeky skill before bed. Not as much as I&apos;d like but had drinks with co-workers after work so *shrug* ^_^</p>", "account_id": "434", "tag_list": [], "media_attachments": [], "emojis": [], "mentions": []}
{"id": "99014544879467317", "created_at": "2017-11-16T14:20:54.462Z", "sensitive": false}  this is how my data look like

Comment: still getting  this error ValueError: Unmatched ''"' when decoding 'string'

Answer (score 0):

### Use [pandas.io.json.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

#### Data:

- Given the data as a `list` of `dicts` in a file named `test.json`

```py
[{
        "id": "99014576299056245",
        "created_at": "2017-11-16T14:28:53.919Z",
        "sensitive": false,
        "spoiler_text": "",
        "language": "en",
        "uri": "mastodon.gamedev.place/users/jaggy/statuses/99014576299056245",
        "instance": "mastodon.gamedev.place",
        "content": "<p>Coding a cheeky skill before bed. Not as much as I&apos;d like but had drinks with co-workers after work so shrug ^_^</p>",
        "account_id": "434",
        "tag_list": [],
        "media_attachments": [],
        "emojis": [],
        "mentions": []
    }, {
        "id": "99014544879467317",
        "created_at": "2017-11-16T14:20:54.462Z",
        "sensitive": false,
        "spoiler_text": "",
        "language": "en",
        "uri": "mastodon.gamedev.place/users/jaggy/statuses/99014544879467317",
        "instance": "mastodon.gamedev.place",
        "content": "<p>Coding a cheeky skill before bed. Not as much as I&apos;d like but had drinks with co-workers after work so shrug ^_^</p>",
        "account_id": "434",
        "tag_list": [],
        "media_attachments": [],
        "emojis": [],
        "mentions": []
    }
]
```

#### Code to read the data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
from pathlib import Path
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# path to file
p = Path(r'c:\some_directory_with_data\test.json')

# read the file in and load using the json module
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# create a dataframe
df = json_normalize(data)

# dataframe view
                id                created_at  sensitive spoiler_text language                                                            uri                instance                                                                                                                       content account_id tag_list media_attachments emojis mentions
 99014576299056245  2017-11-16T14:28:53.919Z      False                    en  mastodon.gamedev.place/users/jaggy/statuses/99014576299056245  mastodon.gamedev.place  <p>Coding a cheeky skill before bed. Not as much as I&apos;d like but had drinks with co-workers after work so shrug ^_^</p>        434       []                []     []       []
 99014544879467317  2017-11-16T14:20:54.462Z      False                    en  mastodon.gamedev.place/users/jaggy/statuses/99014544879467317  mastodon.gamedev.place  <p>Coding a cheeky skill before bed. Not as much as I&apos;d like but had drinks with co-workers after work so shrug ^_^</p>        434       []                []     []       []
```

### Option 2:

#### Data

- The data is in a file, in the form of rows of dicts

  - Not in a list
  - Separated with a newline
- This is not a valid JSON file

```py
{"id": "99014576299056245", "created_at": "2017-11-16T14:28:53.919Z", "sensitive": false, "spoiler_text": "", "language": "en", "uri": "mastodon.gamedev.place/users/jaggy/statuses/99014576299056245", "instance": "mastodon.gamedev.place", "content": "<p>Coding a cheeky skill before bed. Not as much as I&apos;d like but had drinks with co-workers after work so shrug ^_^</p>", "account_id": "434", "tag_list": [], "media_attachments": [], "emojis": [], "mentions": []}
{"id": "99014544879467317", "created_at": "2017-11-16T14:20:54.462Z", "sensitive": false, "spoiler_text": "", "language": "en", "uri": "mastodon.gamedev.place/users/jaggy/statuses/99014544879467317", "instance": "mastodon.gamedev.place", "content": "<p>Coding a cheeky skill before bed. Not as much as I&apos;d like but had drinks with co-workers after work so shrug ^_^</p>", "account_id": "434", "tag_list": [], "media_attachments": [], "emojis": [], "mentions": []}
```

#### Code to read this data

- Reading the file in with the following code

  - `data` will be a list of `str`, where each row of the file, is a `str` in the list
  - Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the `str` back to a dict
  - `literal_eval` won't work if there are invalid values in the `str` (e.g. false instead of False, true instead of True).
  - This will cause a `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x000002B7240B7888>`, which isn't a particularly helpful error
- I've added a `try-except` block to print any row that causes an issue, add to the `values_to_fix` `dict` until you get them all.

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
from pathlib import Path
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from ast import literal_eval

# path to file
p = Path(r'c:\some_directory_with_data\test.json')

list_of_dicts = list()
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for x in data:
        values_to_fix = {'false': 'False',
                         'true': 'True',
                         'none': 'None'}
        for k, v in values_to_fix.items():
            x = x.replace(k, v)
        try:
            x = literal_eval(x)
            list_of_dicts.append(x)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            print(x)

df = json_normalize(list_of_dicts)

# this output is the same as that shown above
```